# Python Grocery Store

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I've been working on this for a few days...

I need to assign the money value of the items and print them out with the corresponding item.

This is what I got so far.

```
 items = [('Diapers', 10), ('Peanut Butter', 5), ('Butter', 6), ('Cheese', 
 3), ('Milk', 3.5), ('Yogurt', 1.99), ('Eggs', 4.5), ('Bread', 4), 
 ('Shrimp', 
 2.5), ('Coffee', 1.5)]

 totalmoney = 50

 print ('You have', totalmoney, "dollars!")

 print('This is your options: \n')

 for item in items:
      print(item[0])
```

And after that I need to ask the user what they want and it should take money away from "totalmoney"

I think I do this by:

```
 if item == item:
      totalmoney - amount

 print(toatalmoney)
```

And if they want to buy or return the item they will have the ability to buy or return.

After the purchase I need to print out total amount of money they have left.

I know how to do this:

```
 print(totalmoney)
```

Then at the end I have to print out what the user has bought and how much money they have left. I would think I do this with a variable such as:

```
 itemsincart = ?
 print(itemsincart)
 print(totalmoney)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you read more tutorial on python since this is a pretty large question. Check out [for loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) and [while loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm) because you'll need them. Also, please have a look to [the stackoverflow guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to asking a good question.
Then, in order to print the items in cart, you will have to put em all in a list and iterate over that list. Something like:

```
for item in cartList:
    print(item[0])
```

Which will print the first element of you item tuples, the name of the item.

Comment: Thank you for you response! I would also like to print out the amount of that item.

Comment: You can use a dictionary instead of a list for you cart. Then, the key can be the name of the item and the value can be the amount of the item in cart